# To define operator of closure, interior

Tags: macros, math-operators

I am using Scientific workplace 5.5, when I define the math operator in this program, it defines it as \limfunc{} as below. When I type this in preamble it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this?
How can define math operator using \limfunc{}?

I wrote a big file in Scientific workplace 5.5, so I don't want to rewrite the codes, I want to get it done by defining operator in preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\limfunc{Int}}{Int} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\limfunc{cl}}{cl}
\begin{document}
$\limfunc{Int}A=\limfunc{cl}A$

$card\beta \mathbb{N}=card\beta \mathbb{Q}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Pleease tell us how or where `\limfunc` is defined. (It's not defined in either the `amsmath` or the `amssymb` package, is it?)

Comment: Off-topic: You may be aware that MacKichan Software, the maker of Scientific Workplace (SWP), [went out of business](https://www.mackichan.com/) in mid-2021. I understand and appreciate that you may have a substantial amount of human capital invested in mastering the ways of getting working papers done in the integrated setting of SWP. Sadly, SWP is becoming more obsolete every single day. If you aren't willing to make the jump all the way to "straight" [!] LaTeX, you may want to consider learning how to use [lyx](https://www.lyx.org/) as an integrated front-end environment to LaTeX.

Comment: Sorry, but you keep asking the same question.

Answer (score 1):

TeX and LaTeX "math operator" macros -- such as `\sin`, `\cos`, `\det`, `\log`, `\exp`, and `\lim` -- are generally typeset using upright ("Roman") lettering.

If that's the typographic convention you wish to observe for `\Int`, `\cl`, and `\card`, there's no need for a detour via `\limfunc` (however it may be defined). Instead, just load the `amsmath` package, which provides the `\DeclareMathOperator` macro, and execute

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Int}{Int} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}
```

in the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} % for \mathbb macro
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \DeclareMathOperator macro
\DeclareMathOperator{\Int}{Int} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}
\DeclareMathOperator{\card}{card}

\begin{document}
$\Int A=\cl A$ \quad
$\card\beta \mathbb{N}=\card\beta \mathbb{Q}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `\DeclareMathOperator` is

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\cmd}{operator}
```

For example, after

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\supp}{supp}
```

you can use the command `\supp` to produce upright 'supp' with proper spacing around it.

```
\supp f = \overline{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid f(x)\neq 0}.
```

In addition, there is a command called `\operatorname` which you can use directly in the math formulas, for example,

```
\operatorname{supp} f = \overline{x\in\mathbb{R} \mid f(x)\neq 0}.
```

However, if you need to use some operator frequently, using `\DeclareMathOperator` to define it is a better choice.